# Abrir ventana para impresion desde controlador php en codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

Hola estoy tratando de abrir una ventana de impresion que contiene los datos de un ticket de pago, actualmente tengo un boton para llamar esa funcion en la vista principal con javascript, pero quisiera que salga automaticamente cuando se le de confirmar el pago, ese boton de confirmar esta en otra vista y llama a la funcion de pagar del controlador, seria posible que ese boton ejecute dos funciones como la del pago y la vez abrir una ventana para imprmir el ticket? Espero puedan ayudarme. les dejo lo que tengo de codigo.

Esta es la funcion de pagar desde el controlador

```
public function pay($id = null){
       $parking_data = $this->model_parking->getParkingData($id);
       $isPaid = $parking_data['paid_status'];
       if(!in_array('viewParking', $this->permission)) {
           redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
       }
       if($id) {
           if($this->input->post('confirm')) {
               if($isPaid==0){
                   $pay = $this->model_parking->updatePayment($id,'1');
                   if($pay == true) {
                   $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Pagado exitosamente');
                   redirect('parking/', 'refresh');
                   }
                   else {
                   $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Se produjo un error!!');
                   redirect('parking/pay/'.$id, 'refresh');
                   }
               }
               else{
                   $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Este parqueo ya esta pagado');
                   redirect('parking/', 'refresh');
               }

           }   
           else {
               $this->data['id'] = $id;
               $this->render_template('parking/pay', $this->data); 
           }
       }
   }
```

Aqui esta el boton de confirmar el pago que llama el metodo anterior

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('parking/pay/'.$id) ?>" method="post">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="confirm" value="Confirmar">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url('parking') ?>" class="btn btn-warning">Cancelar</a>
</form>
```

Esta es otra funcion con la que creo el ticket

```
public function printInvoice($id)
    {
        if(!in_array('viewParking', $this->permission)) {
            redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
        }

        if($id) {
            $parking_data = $this->model_parking->getParkingData($id);
            $company_info = $this->model_company->getCompanyData(1);
            // get the vehicle type 
            $vehicle_category = $this->model_category->getCategoryData($parking_data['vechile_cat_id']);

            $check_in_date = date("Y-m-d", $parking_data['in_time']);
            $check_in = date("h:i a", $parking_data['in_time']);
            $description = $parking_data['description'];


                $check_out_date = date("Y-m-d", $parking_data['out_time']);
                $check_out = date("h:i a", $parking_data['out_time']);
                $total = $parking_data['earned_amount'];
                $html = '<html>
                <head>
                    <title>Imprimir Ticket de Salida</title>
                    <style>
                    .main-content {
                        text-align: center;
                        width: 100%;
                    }

                    table.table {
                        width: 50%;
                        margin: 0 auto;
                        text-align: left;
                    }
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div class="main-content">
                        <div class="company-info">
                            <div class="company-name"><p>'.$company_info['name'].'</p></div>
                            <div class="company-address"><p>'.$company_info['address'].'</p></div>
                            <div class="company-address"><p>------------------------------------------------------</p></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="parking-info">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Fecha Entrada: '.$check_in_date.'</td>
                                    <td>Hora Entrada: '.$check_in.'</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Fecha Salida: '.$check_out_date.'</td>
                                    <td>Hora Salida: '.$check_out.'</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Parqueo no: '.$parking_data['parking_code'].' </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Tipo de vehículo: '.ucwords($vehicle_category['name']).' </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Descripción: '.$description.' </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Total a pagar: $'.$total.'.00 </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                            <p> Para su propia conveniencia, por favor no pierda el ticket. </p>
                            <img alt="testing" src="/parking/barcode?text='.$parking_data['parking_code'].'&size=40&print=true""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="parking-message">
                            '.$company_info['message'].'
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                </body>
            </html>
            ';              
                echo $html;
}
```

y la llamo con este javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function printParking(parking_url)
    {   
      $.ajax({
        url: parking_url,
        type: 'get',
        success:function(response) {
          var mywindow = window.open('', 'PrintWindow', 'height=400,width=600');
          mywindow.document.write(response);
          mywindow.document.close();
          mywindow.focus(); 
          mywindow.print();
          mywindow.close(); 

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla de solucionarlo es incluyendo "onload="window.print()" en la etiqueta Body de la plantilla que utilizas para mostrar los datos, así cuando el controlador cargue la plantilla el navegador automáticamente carga el modo impresión.

La etiqueta debe quedar así: `<body onload="window.print()">`